# Unexpected Acess violation (itoa)

Tags: c++, access-violation, itoa

In K&R book, there is itoa code in Chapter 3 on 64th page. I tried to compile the code, but i was not successful. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
void itoa(int, char*);

int main(void) {
    _getch();
    char arr[100];
    itoa(-18,arr);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void itoa(int n, char* s) {
    int i, sign;
    if ((sign = n) < 0) {
        n = -n;
    }
    i = 0;
    do {
        s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';
    } while ((n / 10) > 0);
    if (sign < 0) s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = 0;
    //reverse(s);
}
```

Output:

> Access violation on line 25, which is: `s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';`

Comment: `(n / 10)` --> `(n /= 10)`

Comment: That is not a compilation error.

Comment: Sure that `s[i++]` doesn't go out of bounds?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `s[i++]` will go out of bounds because the loop never ends if it was branched once, since `n` is not assigned. (see BLUEPIXY's comment)

Comment: `#include <conio.h>` isn't c++ standard. May be just use `getc();` instead of `_getch();`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It's C code semi-hacked so it can sort of be compiled by a C++ compiler.  K&R is a C book; all the programs are C programs.

Comment: Note that this algorithm doesn't work when the value of the argument is `INT_MIN` and the computer is 'normal' (uses 2's complement arithmetic).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Was `conio.h` ever part of the c standards?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No, `<conio.h>` is restricted to Windows (DOS?); it is not a part of the C, C++ or POSIX standards.  The `using namespace std;` is completely bogus as C code too, of course.   (IIRC, the programs in K&R 2nd Edn were tested with a C++ compiler, circa 1988, because Standard C compilers were not yet available).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So what about my comment you're arguing in particular? Or did I misunderstood?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: To the extent I'm arguing, I'm arguing with you and/or the world that the code from K&R is not intended to be C++ code (so discussing whether `<conio.h>` is part of the C++ standard is tangential).  I intensely dislike the dual-tagging of the question, but I can't work out what's the best way to fix it (other than delete it since the problem is mainly that the code in the question isn't an accurate copy of the code in the book).

Comment: @Jonathan _"since the problem is mainly that the code in the question isn't an accurate copy of the code in the book"_ Well, I have to admit it was the last millennium I took a look at that book :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itoa` has an endless loop that exceeds the bounds of `arr` after 100 digits are generated. The loop is not modifying `n` so it can terminate when `n` reaches 0.  Change the `while` condition to use `n /= 10` instead of `n / 10`.

Comment: I see, not n/2 but n/=2.

Comment: if the answer is correct, consider accepting it.

Comment: I did now. I wasnt able because of the time limit.